# How do I remove the visibility of spaces between inline elements?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, inline, block

Say I have several inline-block div tags, like this

```
<div class="image">

</div>
<div class="image">

</div>
```

class image just sets their size to 100x100 and a gray background color. Their margin and borders are set to 0, and yet there is spacing between the two rectangles.

If I write the HTML such as this, however:

```
<div class="image">

</div><div class="image">

</div>
```

Removing all whitespace between the divs, the spacing disappears.

Since I don't want to write my HTML like that, I'm thinking that there must be a way to remove whitespace using CSS. I don't care if the whitespace is removed, hidden or downsized as long as it's visibility is removed.

Thanks for any help

---

As requested, JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6h3Jx/

---

Updated with word-spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/6h3Jx/1/

Comment: This is weird, do you have a live example? Also, which browser are you testing in?

Comment: it shouldn't happen the way you said...can you make a jsfiddle example

Comment: Updated question with JSFiddle link

Comment: @josh-crozier Excuse me, but how is this the duplicate when this question is two years older?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is an inline element behaviour, so try floating left. http://jsfiddle.net/aVrSx/

Comment: I can't both float left and center an element. At least I haven't figured out how - any ideas?

Comment: you want these elements centered in a container?

Comment: I want them to be centered, and break to the next line if the elements exceed the width of the container. A perfect task for inline-block :)

Answer (score 1):

you can set "display: flex;" attribute to their parent wrapper:

```
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the following on a parent element:

```
word-spacing:-4px;
```

Or try:

```
font-size:0px;
```

It might work even better as it will not be affected by text resizing.

Comment: That did absolutely nothing :-)

Comment: yes, i forgot that word-spacing:0; is the default value. -4px should do the trick. However this will be affected by text resizing, so i've added a second solution to my answer.

Comment: Is there also a value that would hinder font-size:0px; from being inherited down the hierarchy? EDIT: No matter, the font-size solution doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/6h3Jx/1/

Comment: nope, the only solution would be something like .nowhitespace{font-size:0px;}      nowhitespace > * { font-size:12px;}