# New line between anchors in HTML source creates empty space in browser

Tags: html, whitespace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove the visibility of spaces between inline elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722222/how-do-i-remove-the-visibility-of-spaces-between-inline-elements)

I usually format my source code to be easy read by humans, AFAIK browsers remove any `\n\t` characters from the source, so they do not get into the rendered html.

Today I built a menu that had a few pixels between 2 anchors in the rendered html and I couldn't find the source of that "empty" space in CSS/HTML. After a few hours I remove the new line (`\n`) between the 2 anchors in the source (just in case) and the empty space disappeared.

I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yR2cS/).

The first menu element has the anchors in the same line in the source code, the other 2 menu items have a new line between the anchors. (hover the menu element to see what I'm talking about). I have the same behaviour in Firefox 8.0, Firefox Nightly 11.0a1 (2011-12-01) and Chromium 14.0.835.202 (Developer Build 103287 Linux) Ubuntu 11.10.

I just can't understand why is this happening.

What I did wrong and how can I avoid this behaviour (without changing the readability of the source code) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Anchors are inline elements. If you add a white-space (space, tab, newine, ..) between the elements, a gap will appear.

Depending on the situation, you can use either of the following methods to get rid of the gap:

- Add a negative `margin-left`, e.g. `margin-left:-4px;`
- Use `float`, e.g. `float:left;`
- Remove the whitespace between the elements. To keep the code somewhat readable, you can break after the opening tag, eg:

  ```
  <a href="..">Link</a><a
     href="..">Link 2</a>
  ```

Comment: Although that shouldn't result in a vertical shift, unless they are accidentally at the end of a line.

Comment: I have learned something new today, Thank you