# Why does a character trail after the hyperlink tag by one space when coded in a specific way?

Tags: html, hyperlink

The character used in this question examples is the period, it appears that all characters behave the same way.  Why does the period trail after the hyperlink by one space character when coded like this:

```
You can become one of us 
    <a href="http://www.somedomain.com/oneOfUs/allYourBaseAreBelongToUs/">
here
</a>
.
```

I checked the ascii character array for the above and it looks to be a simple space:
104 101 114 101 **32** 46

vs no trailing space after the hyperlink when coded like this:

```
You can become one of us 
    <a href="http://www.somedomain.com/oneOfUs/allYourBaseAreBelongToUs/">here</a>.
```

The ascii character array for the above contains no space in output, but providing the character array for output comparison: 104 101 114 101 46

Comment: You have a newline in the first sample. Newlines and multiple spaces are replaced by a single space (if you do not use `<pre>` or the CSS property `white-space`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the newline in the first example is converted to a space.  There is a more thorough explanation in this thread: [Prevent browser converting '\n' between lines into space (for Chinese characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550112/prevent-browser-converting-n-between-lines-into-space-for-chinese-characters)