# How to place divs one next to another without floatant?

Tags: html, css

I managed to place two divs one next to the other using `float: left`, but the div below doesn't display properly : http://jsfiddle.net/N4kE3/2/

And with this css for each div :

```
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/N4kE3/3/

They are one above the other. I have to put `width: 49%` to make them be one next to the other.

How is that possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove the visibility of spaces between inline elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722222/how-do-i-remove-the-visibility-of-spaces-between-inline-elements)

Comment: If you have any padding, border applied to it then width is not that which you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to keep your floats you could use a clearfix on the container:

<kbd>[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N4kE3/4/)</kbd>

```
#action:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

If you wish to use`inline-block` you need to remove the white space in your markup:

<kbd>[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N4kE3/5/)</kbd>

This..

```
    <div id="action">
        <div id="buy" class="action">Buy</div>
        <div id="sell" class="action">Sell</div>
    </div>
```

Becomes...

```
<div id="action">
    <div id="buy" class="action">Buy</div><div id="sell" class="action">Sell</div>
</div>
```

.. otherwise the white space will be taken into account when calculating the widths making 50% + 50% + whitespace = more than 100%. Thats just how `inline-block` works.

Answer (score 1):

The space between elements is displayed. Imagine `<strong>Hello</strong> <em>world</em>`. This is displayed as "**Hello** *world*". See the space between Hello and World.

An enter and multiple spaces are collapsed to a single space.

```
  <strong>Hello</strong>
  <em>world</em>
```

becomes "**Hello** *world*".

The same is happening with your divs. They are both 50% of the screen, but the space also takes up 10 pixels, pushing the 2nd div to the next line.

There are several ways of solving this. Using `float`, using `display: table-cell` or (as I usually prefer) by eliminating the space between the divs using XML comments `<!-- -->`.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="action">
        <div id="buy" class="action">Buy</div><!--
     --><div id="sell" class="action">Sell</div>
    </div>
    <div id="other">test</div>
</div>
```

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/N4kE3/6/)

Comment: Can't we use `<span>` in this case ?